# Ubuntu 20.04 - Raspberry PI 4 (4GB) Official 7" Screen - No Touch

Tags: raspberrypi

I recently upgraded from 19.10 to 20.04 on my Raspberry Pi 4. I have the official 7" touch screen attached and mounted to my wall in a case. After the upgrade, the touch part of the screen no longer works. I didn't see anything in the known issues notes.

Any troubleshooting hints would be helpful. If all else fails, I can try to reinstall the complete 20.04 OS from scratch or even downgrade if needed.

I've tried this command

```
dmesg | grep -i ft5406
```

inspired by this [www.raspberrypi.org](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/display/troubleshooting.md) article.

I get no output, so I assume the driver is having issues, but now I'm stuck. The link doesn't tell me where to go next with troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running 22.04 and entered this at the end of /boot/firmware/config.txt

display_auto_detect=1

Reboot and enjoy either graphical or text. Touch works on graphical screen.

[config.txt Docs](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/config_txt.html)